# Error message getting displayed but not getting highlighted fields in Drupal 7

Tags: forms, theming

Drupal 7 is not displaying highlighted fields on using `form_set_error` but error message is getting displayed. I have rendered my form hook_form in template. Could that be the cause for this issue?

Here is my code:

```
if(($form_state['values']['field1']=='' ){
 form_set_error('', t('one field is required')); 

 }
```

Answer (score 5):

First argument of [`form_set_error`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/form_set_error/7) tells Drupal what element should get highlighted. Obviously empty string means "none", so your code works exactly as designed.

To make field required, you can go a simpler way: Use [`#required`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#required) attribute and let Drupal take care for details.

To round it off, as Clive said, your code would be:

```
form_set_error('field1', t('one field is required'));
```

But if you're just checking for an empty field, use `#required`.

Comment: To round it off @user25283 your code would be `form_set_error('field1', t('one field is required'));`. But if you're just checking for an empty field, use `#required` as Mołot says

Answer (score 0):

It's not working for me using the below code:

```
  $form['field1'] = array(
        '#title' => t('Field1'),
        '#size' => 24,
        '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#default_value' =>$field ,
    '#required' => TRUE,      
  '#element_validate' => array('function_name'), 


  );

if(($form_state['values']['field1']=='' ){
 form_set_error('field1', t('one field is required')); 

 }
```

getting the error message in red at the top but my text box is not getting highlighted with red border.
I have used this text box in hook_form in a module, but i have called this form in theme using

```
print render(drupal_get_form('hook_form'));
```

I guess the error message is not getting highlighted since am calling this in a theme.

This is getting worked when i call my form in a module but i want the form to be called from a template. In this case my error message is not getting highlighted with red border over the text box.